# Отправка canvas изображения на сервер js c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Нужно отправить canvas изображение на контроллер. Пытаюсь преобразовать `image` в `base64` с помощью `canvas.toDataURL()`, но таким образом все время возвращает null.
 View

```
<div class="l-canvas">
    <canvas id="canvas" width=@ViewData["width"] height=@ViewData["height"]></canvas>
</div>
```

js

```
 function canvasToImage() {

    canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var image = canvas.toDataURL({  //В image всегда приходит null
        format: 'jpeg',
        quality: 1
    });


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "../../Home/UploadImage/",
        data: '{ "imageData" : "' + image + '" }',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, status) {
            alert('success')
        }
    })
}
```

Принимающий метод

```
public ActionResult UploadImage(string image)
{
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(image);
    Session["imageSession"] = data;
    return RedirectToAction("Apply");
}
```

Comment: а в консоль выводить пробовали?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, у вас ошибка в действии контроллера, не верно указан входящий параметр, вместо `imageData` ожидаете `image`, вот он всегда и `Null` у вас. Ну и с объектом аякса слишком намудрили, упростил:

переработанная отправка

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
    url: "../../Home/UploadImage/",
    data: {imageData : image}
    }).success(function (data, status) {
       alert('success')
    }).error(function(err){
       console.log(err);
    });
```

Действие:

```
// тут у вас была ошибка
public ActionResult UploadImage(string imageData)
{
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
    Session["imageSession"] = data;
    return RedirectToAction("Apply");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, исправил заработало все.